# MariaDB MAX sort failing

Tags: mysql, mariadb, max

EDIT: I've reworked the question and example since the previous example only included one city.

I'm looking to find **one row per city** with either the highest max_wind OR max_gust value.

Here's a basic query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f63e/2):

```
        SELECT *
          FROM high_wind 
         WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR;                                                                              
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| hid  | city      | max_wind | max_gust | timestamp           |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 4784 | Vancouver | 63       | 90       | 2021-01-13 08:26:00 |
| 4785 | Vancouver | 54       | 71       | 2021-01-13 08:40:00 |
| 4786 | Calgary   | 52       | 71       | 2021-01-13 15:35:00 |
| 4787 | Calgary   | 57       | 79       | 2021-01-13 17:53:00 |
| 4788 | Calgary   | 67       | 86       | 2021-01-13 18:14:00 |
| 4789 | Calgary   | 70       | 84       | 2021-01-13 18:40:00 |
| 4790 | Calgary   | 51       | 86       | 2021-01-13 19:00:00 |
| 4791 | Calgary   | 55       | 75       | 2021-01-13 20:00:00 |
| 4792 | Saskatoon | 66       | 81       | 2021-01-14 00:18:00 |
| 4793 | Saskatoon | 53       | 73       | 2021-01-14 01:26:00 |
| 4794 | Saskatoon | 59       | 77       | 2021-01-14 01:44:00 |
| 4795 | Saskatoon | 72       | 91       | 2021-01-14 02:00:00 |
| 4796 | Saskatoon | 77       | 103      | 2021-01-14 03:00:00 |
| 4797 | Saskatoon | 52       | 65       | 2021-01-14 05:00:00 |
| 4798 | Saskatoon | 57       | 68       | 2021-01-14 06:13:00 |
| 4799 | Saskatoon | 50       | 64       | 2021-01-14 09:00:00 |
| 4800 | Saskatoon | 51       | 61       | 2021-01-14 15:00:00 |
| 4801 | Resolute  | 51       |          | 2021-01-15 04:00:00 |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
18 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

From the above data sample, this would be the final intended result:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| hid  | city      | max_wind | max_gust | timestamp           |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 4784 | Vancouver | 63       | 90       | 2021-01-13 08:26:00 |
| 4788 | Calgary   | 67       | 86       | 2021-01-13 18:14:00 |
| 4796 | Saskatoon | 77       | 103      | 2021-01-14 03:00:00 |
| 4801 | Resolute  | 51       |          | 2021-01-15 04:00:00 |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I thought I had found a solution with the following INNER JOIN query, however the results are mixed. Here it correctly produced two results, but missed two others.

```
        SELECT *
          FROM high_wind a 
          JOIN 
             ( SELECT city
                    , MAX(max_wind) max_wind
                   , MAX(max_gust) max_gust 
              FROM high_wind
             WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR 
             GROUP 
                BY city
             ) b 
            ON a.city = b.city 
           AND a.max_wind = b.max_wind 
           AND a.max_gust = b.max_gust 
         WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR;          
                    
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| hid  | city      | max_wind | max_gust | timestamp           |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 4784 | Vancouver | 63       | 90       | 2021-01-13 08:26:00 |
| 4801 | Resolute  | 51       |          | 2021-01-15 04:00:00 |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.006 sec)
```

Comment: It's not true to say that the city/datetime with the highest windspeed is the same as the city/datetime with the highest gust.you need to identify both then join back to the data using distinct if the do happen to be the same city/datetime

Comment: Added: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88365d/7

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hw.*
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(wind) AS max_wind,
               MAX(gust) AS max_gust
            FROM high_wind
            WHERE ...
         ) AS mx
    JOIN high_wind AS hw  ON (   hw.wind = mx.max_wind
                              OR hw.gust = mx.max_gust )
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

You might get 1 row if the maxes are for the same city and time.

You might more than 2 rows if there are identical values for MAX(..) for different cities or times.

If you have a million rows in high_wind, we can discuss indexes to help with performance.  My query will require 2 full table scans unless you add `INDEX(wind)` and `INDEX(gust)`.  But if you need something in the `WHERE` (eg a province limitation or date range), those indexes won't suffice.

For simply `WHERE timestamp > ...`, add

```
INDEX(timestamp)
INDEX(wind, timestamp)
INDEX(gust, timestamp)
```

**More**

Do *not* use `VARCHAR` for numeric (or date) values:

```
`max_wind` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
```

With that, "102" is less than "99" !

Comment: Thanks for the example! The intention is to run this query every X hours with a range of the previous X hours (ie. NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR).

Comment: @skyblaster - If there are "many" entries per hour, then I would push you toward building and maintaining a "summary table".  But there seem to be very few readings per 8 (or 12 or 13) hours?

Comment: that is correct. There are less than 50 towns/cities being monitored on an "hourly" basis and only winds exceeding 50km/h are recorded to this table.

Comment: @skyblaster - So, there could be hours, even days, with no rows in the table?  This may lead to extra code to recognize that situation and deliver `NULL` or whatever.

Comment: I've reworked the question and feel like I'm getting closer. Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f63e/15

Comment: @skyblaster - I spotted a bad bug in the schema; see my addition to my Answer.  If, after fixing the datatype, there is still an issue, I will look closer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rick James I've corrected this and added some older fake data and getting closer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7c04/1